# PDAL pipeline could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, lidar, pdal, docker

I am trying to import .las files to the postgres database. My pipeline is:

```
{
  "pipeline":[
{
  "type":"readers.las",
  "filename":"data/pt000002.las",
  "spatialreference":"EPSG:4326"
},
{
  "type":"filters.chipper",
  "capacity":500
},
{
  "type":"writers.pgpointcloud",
  "connection":"host='localhost' dbname='db_example' user='postgres' password='super'",
  "table":"las2",
  "compression":"dimensional",
  "srid":"4326"
}
  ]
}
```

This pipeline is worked for me before when I have PDAL installed in Conda environment. Now, I have PDAL installed in Docker environment, and when I call pipeline with:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/user/Documents/projectX:/data pdal/pdal:1.7 pdal pipeline /data/laz2pg.txt
```

I get the error:

```
 pdal/pdal:1.7 pdal pipeline /data/laz2pg.txt 
 PDAL: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 could not connect to server: Address not available
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

All answers are true. Anyway, I used the same database when I used PDAL with conda. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

Comment: Quick-and-dirty fix should be to add `--net=host` to your `docker run` command, if you have no problem with your container using your host's network interface.

Comment: Write that as an answer and I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `localhost` inside of your Docker container refers to the container, not the host where Postgres is running. If you add `--net=host` to your `docker run` commend, then your Docker container will use the host's networking stack, and `localhost` will work as you expect.